# Factory requires only declaration of copy ctor without implementation

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I'm experiencing behavior which I don't understand in a copy constructor of derived class.

```
class A {
    A(const A&);

public:
    A() = default;
};

class B : public A {
    friend class Factory;
    B(const int v) : A(), m_test_val(v) {}

public:
    int m_test_val;
    B(const B&); // no implementation, just declaration
};

class Factory {
public:
    static B create(const int v) {
        return B(v);
    }
};

int main() {
    B b = Factory::create(2);
    std::cout << b.m_test_val << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The behavior I don't understand is a matter of a working copy constructor `B::B(const B&);` which, however, does not have any implementation.

When I use `B::B(const B&) = default;` instead, I get an error saying I'm using deleted function (implicitly deleted because of ill-formation) in the return statement of the Factory::create() function (The A::A(const A&) is private and without implementation on purpose).

And of course, when I use `B::B(const B&) = delete;`, compiler tells me I use a deleted function.

**How is it possible that the copy constructor works with no implementation just with declaration?**

*Note: The example code is based on a much larger code that behaves the same way, hopefully I didn't leave something out.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual copy is elided by the compiler, which is allowed since the copy constructor is accessible. The compiler is of course under no obligation to elide this copy and if it didn't I would expect a linker error not finding the implementation of the copy constructor.

Comment: That's what I thought in the first place but it even works with -O0 in g++ 6.3.1 and in clang 3.9.1. Or the optimization level does no matter in this case?

Comment: Just tried to compile with `-fno-elide-constructors` and finally, to my satisfaction, the linking fails! Thanks for the keyword 'elide'.